# Anyway to bring up suggestion box when typing python code

Tags: python

I'm learning wxpython right now and one thing that helps me ALOT is when I'm typing in the text editor I sometimes press the tab key to give me a hint on what I'm looking for...This is great when it works but I notice sometimes it doesn't work and I get lost looking for a syntax I can't remember...

Question is how can I get the suggestion box to pop back up again, Or what am I doing that causes it to stop coming up...

if it matters I backtracked to 2.7 to learn wx, Windows 7

Edit: More specifically... when I type: wx.(Here is normally when I would press tab)

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what editor you're using...

Comment: Although this probably won't solve the problem you have, its worth noting that python has 2 build in functions: dir() and help(). dir() lists methods/attributes of a given object white help displays a doc string for a function/object. Other than that, consider using a different editor. Eclipse with pydev is very good.

Answer (score 0):

What editor do you use??

Without knowing that there's no way we can possibly help you.

FWIW in vim I use `C-x [onp]`

Comment: Oh, ok. I believe that environment is called IDLE. Including that with you question will probably help people to help you, I'm afriad I don't know how it works.